# How to hash password before saving to db to be compatible with passport module (passport local)

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using passport-local strategy of passport for authentication. In my express server, I am getting a register post request and I should save password to db for a new user. But I need to hash the password before saving to db.

But I am not sure how to hash it, since passport will authenticate user by hashing the login password credential to match my hashed password from db. How should I hash my passwords ?

I am using this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`passport-local` does not hash your passwords - it [passes the credentials to your verify callback](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/c5a349b1fce71c51d66f78f8fc3e3861444b9a04/lib/strategy.js#L87-L90) for verification and you take care of handling the credentials. Thus, you can use any hash algorithm but I believe [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) is the most popular.

You hash the password in your register handler:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  // Whatever verifications and checks you need to perform here
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      newUser.password = hash; // Or however suits your setup
      // Store the user to the database, then send the response
    });
  });
});
```

Then in your verify callback you compare the provided password to the hash:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, cb) {
  // Locate user first here
  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, res) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (res === false) {
      return cb(null, false);
    } else {
      return cb(null, user);
    }
  });
}));
```

Comment: How do I this with `passport-local-mongoose` package which hashes with PBKDF2 and not bcrypt?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-authenticate

```
var auth = require('passport-local-authenticate');

auth.hash('password', function(err, hashed) {
  console.log(hashed.hash); // Hashed password
  console.log(hashed.salt); // Salt
});

auth.hash('password', function(err, hashed) {
  auth.verify('password', hashed, function(err, verified) {
    console.log(verified); // True, passwords match
  ));
});

auth.hash('password', function(err, hashed) {
  auth.verify('password2', hashed, function(err, verified) {
    console.log(verified); // False, passwords don't match
  ));
});
```

Comment: Hey man, I have edited my post with the module I am using, your link is a different module. It might apply to mine.

Comment: @FurkanO If you want the ability to hash the password then you'll need to use the module I've linked.

Comment: But mine does authentication too, it should require a type of hash algorithm too. I guess there is a standart way everybody knows or sth. But If nobody answers I ll use yours. Thanks for your post.

Comment: @FurkanO You can use both modules -- the `password-local-authenticate` module uses the following to hash the password: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback

Answer (score 2):

Why should we go for hashing algorithm, when passport already provided it for us? I mean we just need to plugin the passport-local-mongoose to our user schema like: `UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)` and then, inside the register route we just tell the `passportLocalMongoose` to do the hashing for us by using:

```
User.register(new User({username:req.body.username}), req.body.password,function(err,newUser)
{ 
    if(err){
        something
    }else{
        something
    }
)
```

By doing above we don't need to take care of hashing and it will be done for us. Please correct me if I am wrong or got your question wrong.