# Security in nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, express, passport.js

I am new to NodeJS and have made a web application login feature using passport.

I know when someone registers an account, the app needs to hash their password and save the hash to the database. But when I use `console.log()`, the object still contains the user's password in plain text. I have a feeling it's not safe but I'm not sure how to approach this. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, don't roll your own security routines in production environments.

Comment: Are you using https?I also agree with @David Stockinger - you shouldn't roll your own security routines in production environments

Comment: First, you need to post your code.  Second, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668680/how-to-hash-password-before-saving-to-db-to-be-compatible-with-passport-module .

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether it is node.js or any other framework used for backend development, it is a good practice to pass the sensitive data such as passwords in encrypted format.

Typically we prefer using Json Web Tokens(JWT) - https://jwt.io/

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken to encrypt and decrypt it.

Comment: No, typically you hash the password using bcrypt, pbkdf2, argon2, or scrypt.

Comment: So, passing the password as plain text over the network is fine?

Comment: No, you pass it over https.  JWTs add no value here.

Comment: JWTs are treated as access tokens, not password encryption

Answer (score 0):

**Don't bother too much with it.**

If a malicious agent has access to the runtime environment of your server he will be able to do, possibly, everything. Even if you are using jwt he will be able to get the secret and decode it easily.

Focus on:

- leaving the password encrypted in the database (as you did very well)
- using SSL between you and the entry point on your servers network
- making sure that you only expose the necessary, having a firewall/barrier in the exterior of your server is a very good pratice
- sanitize and validate your server inputs to avoid injections and exploits

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say only on don't use third party API or packages for it