# How to check if user is logged in with node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I want let's say p.x on /profile I want to know if the user is logged in with a command!

So when he goes to home page "/" it's going to render either the profile.ejs if he is logged in or the home.ejs to register and log in.But I don't when do that with app.get('/login'... because I need it again when I am already using the profile to redirect to another page but he has to be logged in to go there.

Here is code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const passport = require('passport')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
  id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const users = []

var http = require('http');

/* ************ */
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))


app.use( bodyParser.json() );     

var dbConn = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/');

var path = require('path');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nyg', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

app.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  }).exec();

  if (user) {
    res.redirect('/register');
    next();
  }

  else new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  })
    .save()
    .exec();
  res.redirect('/login');
  next();
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  if (user) res.redirect('/');
  else res.redirect('/login');
  next();
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) res.render('profile.ejs')

  else res.render('index.ejs')
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.ejs')
})


app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register.ejs')
})


app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logOut()
  res.redirect('/login')
})



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0' );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) already contains everything you need to log in a user and check if a user is authenticated in any route.

You have correctly identified that the `req.isAuthenticated()` function is provided by the middleware to see if a user is currently authenticated.

The user must be logged in with Passport for the function to work. In your `app.post('/login'` route, make sure that you are authenticating the user against Passport like this:

```
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

[The Passport documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/) clearly explains how to set it up for username and password authentication if your current configuration isn't working. The examples they give already use mongoose to retrieve users from the database.

`req.isAuthenticated()` can then be used in combination with an if statement from any route to conditionally execute code depending on if the user is logged in.

```
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
  // The user is logged in
} else {
  // The user is logged out
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a simple middleware that will only allow access to a route if the user is logged in.

```
function loggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
app.get('/protectedRoute', loggedIn, (req, res) => {
  // The user is logged in otherwise they would have been redirected
})
```

See [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/JacobWrenn/express-passport-demo) for a fully working express & passport login example. Just follow the instructions in the readme to run it.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that but it still didn't work for me. Can you check my code out?
Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/SSMqxVhg

Comment: Hi @Herpryth check out my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/JacobWrenn/express-passport-demo) of a fully working example based on your code. I've updated the answer to include the link. You should be able to put back in your own EJS and CSS once you see how everything works.

Comment: I've also added password hashing as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668680/how-to-hash-password-before-saving-to-db-to-be-compatible-with-passport-module). Never keep passwords in plain text.

Comment: HUGE THANKS it took me days to figure out and still I couldn't. Well, I am a beginner so...THANKS, A LOT.If there is anything I can do let me know.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: Do you have any social media like Discord...So I can contact you for anything else?

Comment: I don't normally help people individually but if you open more questions in the future I will of course try to help

Answer (score 0):

well first write how you want to define it..

Route-login => token found => verify and login and redirect to dashboard.

Route-login => token not found => next()

create a middleware name it anything u want.. (i named it as loginBefore)

```
const User = require("../model/User");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

exports.loginBefore = async (req, res, next) => {
  const tokenFind = () => {
    try {
      // check if token found in cookies
      if (req.cookies.token) {
        return req.cookies.token;
      }
      // check if token found body
      if (req.body.token) {
        return req.body.token;
      }
      //check if token found in header
      if (req.header("Authorization")) {
        return req.header("Authorization").replace("Bearer ", "");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  const token = tokenFind();

  if (token) {
    // decoding the token with scerect key
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWTSECRETWORD);

    // asign to a var
    const found = await User.findById(decoded.id);

    if (found) {
      return res.status(200).redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
  return res.status(400).redirect("/login");
}
  }
  next();
};
```

later go to ur router page

```
const { loginBefore } = require("../middleware/loginBefore");
```

make it require

```
router.route("/login").post(loginBefore, login);
```

then add this below after requiring it. (loginBefore is middleware that checks for token)

```
const userRouter = require("./route/user");

app.use("/", userRouter);
```

then add this in app.js

HOPE THIS HELPS...

i'm checking if token is found in cookies, body or in header then if it was found verify the token and find the user from mongodb using mongoose and redirect user to dashboard.

if token was not found or token contains modified data then redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if ((req.session.userid == "") || (typeof req.session.userid === 'undefined') || (req.session.userid === null)) {
    res.redirect(/* path for login here */)
  } else next() // or do something else if there logged in
})
```

So you would end up with something alike tis:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const sessions = require('express-session');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser());
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // time in milliseconds
//session middleware
app.use(sessions({
    secret: /* your secret here */,
    saveUninitialized:true,
    cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
    resave: false
}));
// All login routes here
app.use(function(req, res, next){
      if ((req.session.userid == "") || (typeof req.session.userid === 'undefined') || (req.session.userid === null)) {
        res.redirect(/* path for login here */)
      } else next() // or do something else if there logged in
    })
//all other routes here
```

it is VERY important that all login routes are BEFORE the check function, otherise it will create an infinite loop! Also, inside the login routes, make sure the following code is added inside the logging in route so that the `req.session.userid` has a value:

```js
req.session.userid = // value or other variable here
```

Feel free to send me any notes, comments, questions & more!